# C++ text file with columns into 2D vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, root

I have a text file that has values and I want to put them into a 2D vector.

I can do it with arrays but I don't know how to do it with vectors.

The vector size should be like vector2D[nColumns][nLines] that I don't know in advance. At the most I can have in the text file the number of columns, but not the number of lines.
The number of columns could be different, from one .txt file to another.

.txt example:

```
189.53  -1.6700 58.550  33.780  58.867
190.13  -3.4700 56.970  42.190  75.546
190.73  -1.3000 62.360  34.640  56.456
191.33  -1.7600 54.770  35.250  65.470
191.93  -8.7500 58.410  33.900  63.505
```

with arrays I do it like this:

```
//------ Declares Array for values ------//
const int nCol = countCols; // read from file
float values[nCol][nLin]; 

// Fill Array with '-1'
for (int c = 0; c < nCol; c++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < nLin; l++) {
        values[c][l] = -1;
    }
}

// reads file to end of *file*, not line 
while (!inFile.eof()) {
    for (int y = 0; y < nLin; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nCol; i++) {
            inFile >> values[i][y];
        }
        i = 0;  
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (!inFile.eof())` is wrong. Stop that!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What should be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
const int nCol = countCols; // read from file
std::vector<std::vector<float>> values;  // your entire data-set of values

std::vector<float> line(nCol, -1.0);  // create one line of nCol size and fill with -1

// reads file to end of *file*, not line 
bool done = false;
while (!done) 
{
    for (int i = 0; !done && i < nCol; i++) 
    {
        done = !(inFile >> line[i]);
    }
    values.push_back(line);  
}
```

Now your dataset has:

```
values.size() // number of lines
```

and can be adressed with array notation also (besides using iterators):

```
float v = values[i][j];
```

Note: this code does not take into account the fact that the last line may have less that nCol data values, and so the end of the line vector will contain wrong values at end of file. You may want to add code to clear the end of the line vector when done becomes false, before you push it into values.

Comment: I've tried but still with some warnings and error on the graphs, the result is not what I was expecting. How can I do it like this: .txt values column 1 -> vector[0][j]; .txt values column 2 -> vector[1][j]; ... ?

Comment: The values vector represents a collection of lines from your data. Your table at (0,0) is at values[0][0] and the third data item in line 2 (56.970) is at values[1][2]. The leftmost index of values vector is the zero-based line number and the rightmost is your column number (zero-based again). This representation is row-major (ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). This is how your original code was reading the values from the file. By 'values column 1 -> vector[0][j]' do you mean you now want your data in column-major format?

Comment: I would like to have the values from the .txt from the first column in values[0][i], from the 3rd column in values[2][i]... So the value (56.970) should be in values[2][1]

Comment: I could also keep using arrays, but I need to reduce the initial size. Is it possible?
Also, is possible to know the number of lines of one file?

Comment: Ok, this seems to be like a column-major format. A std::vector has little memory overhead in itself compared to the data it contains. The hierarchy starts from _Container_base class (no data members), then _Vector_val class (contains allocator object reference) then the vector class template that contains 3 pointers (first, last, end). Simplifying, all in all 4 pointers/references that in a 64 bit system are 8x4 = 32 bytes per vector class instance. In most cases this, compared to the contained data is a very small overhead.

Comment: continued: As for the lines of the file, please read my answer under the code. It is values.size(). As for column-major order it is useful only if you need to perform operations on an entire column, swap columns, etc, in which case you'll need to define another vector<vector<float>> col_major, a vector<float> column(values.size()), then iterate over values like this: for (int c=0; c<nCol; c++) { for (int r=0; r<values.size(); r++) { column[r] = values[r][c]; } col_major.push_back(column); }  [can someone please show me how to format this in a comment?]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
float values[nCol][nLin];
```

use

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> v;
```

You have to `#include<vector>` for this.

Now you don't need to worry about size.

Adding elements is as simple as

`std::vector<float> f; f.push_back(7.5); v.push_back(f);`

Also do not use `.eof()` on streams, because it doesn't set it until after the end has been reached and so it will attempt to read the end of the file.

```
while(!inFile.eof())
```

Should be

```
while (inFile >> values[i][y]) // returns true as long as it reads in data to values[x][y]
```

NOTE: Instead of `vector`, you can also use `std::array`, which is apparently the best thing after sliced bread.

Comment: If the number of columns is known, and constant throughout the entire data-set, then this method can be optimized by defining a single vector outside the loop, re-sizing it to the number of columns, and then setting the values to it repeatedly in the loop, and at the end of each iteration, pushing it into the result vector.

Comment: However i should note `std::vector` as a bit slower than a usual C array. If OP needs maximum performance, he should use `std::vector` with care.

Comment: @DNT, because using `std::array`s is too mainstream

Comment: @Axilles [citation-needed].

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz What do you mean? i don't understand.

Comment: @JMG you can also index vector like C arrays using subscript operator

Comment: "Adding elements is as simple as
std::vector<float> f; f.push_back(7.5); v.push_back(f);"

But how can I do it reading from the columns of the text file?
Each column should be in each vector dimension. Eg.:

    values column 1 -> 1st vector;
    values column 2 -> 2nd vector;
    values column 3 -> 3rd vector;

...

Comment: @Axilles Your statement needs more data to back it up. Access of vector elements is the same pointer arithmetic as access of array elements. Where is it slower? By how much? Does it really matter? Why not use `std::array` instead?

Comment: @Jeffrey std::array is C++ 2011 standard. It is not available in older compilers, and since the compiler version is not specified here, I suggested use of std::vector which is supported by older compilers.

Comment: @JMG what is implied here, is that you should push all values of one line into the std::vector<float> and then push it into your final std::vector<std::vector<float>> before starting on the next line.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I mean the reallocation of memory blocks cost. I.e. vector as dynamic structure can be slower than fixed-size C array or `std::array`. However, this problem can be fixed using huge values in `reserve` function of `std::vector`. Cost of vector object creation and it's operators calls is minimal, i agree.

Comment: @Axilles if the need arises to reallocate C array, the time of reallocation will be as big as with vector, no? So what is the actual gain again?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Ok, i will stop arguing now because i haven't concrete data  of performance differences between `std::vector` and C array. I'm just want to warn OP what they are exists: additional code is required to work with C++ object, isn't it? So it should slow down the program execution to some (small) value.

Comment: @Axilles The code will be removed by the compiler in optimizations, so no, there's no real overhead here.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Sorry for this offtop, but could you name good articles about this: "The code will be removed by the compiler in optimizations". I suspect it will be removed by GOOD compiler only :)

Comment: @Axilles Every recent compiler is good. GNU G++, Clang, MSVS, ICC, all should deal with this sort of trivial optimizations.

Comment: @TonyTheLion I want to use vectors because this way I don't have to know the number of columns or of lines. How can I do this if I don't know this numbers: "while (inFile >> values[i][y]) // returns true as long as it reads in data to values[x][y]"?